Is there a better way to modify or insert a struct in a hashmap in rust?
Im going through the rustlings exercices, and the solution i came up for hashmaps3 is kind of verbose but works.
Just wondering if there is a better/more concise method to do the exercise

// A structure to store team name and its goal details.
struct Team {
    name: String,
    goals_scored: u8,
    goals_conceded: u8,
}

fn build_scores_table(results: String) -> HashMap<String, Team> {
    // The name of the team is the key and its associated struct is the value.
    let mut scores: HashMap<String, Team> = HashMap::new();

    for r in results.lines() {
        let v: Vec<&str> = r.split(',').collect();
        let team_1_name = v[0].to_string();
        let team_1_score: u8 = v[2].parse().unwrap();
        let team_2_name = v[1].to_string();
        let team_2_score: u8 = v[3].parse().unwrap();
        // TODO: Populate the scores table with details extracted from the
        // current line. Keep in mind that goals scored by team_1
        // will be the number of goals conceded from team_2, and similarly
        // goals scored by team_2 will be the number of goals conceded by
        // team_1.
        if scores.contains_key(&team_1_name) {
            let t1:&mut Team = scores.get_mut(&team_1_name).unwrap();
            t1.goals_scored+=team_1_score;
            t1.goals_conceded+=team_2_score;
        }
        else {
            let team_1_struct = Team{
                name:team_1_name.clone(),
                goals_scored:team_1_score.clone(),
                goals_conceded: team_2_score.clone(),
            };

            scores.insert(team_1_name,team_1_struct); };

        if scores.contains_key(&team_2_name) {
            let t2 =scores.get_mut(&team_2_name).unwrap();
            t2.goals_scored+=team_2_score;
            t2.goals_conceded+=team_1_score;

        }
        else {
            let team_2_struct = Team{
                name:team_2_name.clone(),
                goals_scored:team_2_score.clone(),
                goals_conceded: team_1_score.clone(),
            };
            scores.insert(team_2_name,team_2_struct); };
    }
    scores
} 

Short of just abstracting it all onto a function

Take a look at HashMap::entry API.

if let Some(_) = map.get_mut(key)

If you find a solution to your problem, you should post it as an answer below, not edit the question to include it.

replacing the if else statements with .entry() method and updating the struct field with .and_modify() method calls.
scores.entry(team_1_name.clone())
            .and_modify(|team|team.goals_scored+=team_1_score)
            .and_modify(|team|team.goals_conceded+=team_2_score)
            .or_insert(
            Team{
            name:team_1_name.clone(),
            goals_scored:team_1_score.clone(),
            goals_conceded: team_2_score.clone(),
        });

